# wrap symbol of `{}` around react render

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
class App extends React.Component {
  renderSomething = () => `something`
  render() {
    return <div>{` `{` ${this.renderSomething()} `}` `}</div>
  }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/6yomj6wj73

I want to output `{something}` on the screen without modify renderSomething function, any clue why above code failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a template string which surrounds your content in braces, then use *that* in the JSX. I split up the steps into multiple variables which should hopefully make things clearer.

```jsx
class App extends React.Component {
  renderSomething = () => `something`

  render() {
    const innerText = this.renderSomething()
    const wrappedWithBraces = `{${innerText}}`
    return <div>{ wrappedWithBraces }</div>

    // in short: <div>{ `{${this.renderSomething()}}` }</div>
    // but I prefer the non-short version, since it's much more readable :)
  }
}
```